# Is There A Way Other Than Thread.Sleep to Delay the Execution of the Tests

Tags: scala, scalatest

In my test spec, I have instantiate a class which has to do quite a bit of stuff and I want to make sure that it completes all those operations (db indexing) before the tests actually run. The way I have got it working at the moment is:

```scala
class Dbpec extends AnyWordSpec with Matchers{

  val db: DefaultDb = new Repo(dbcomponent)

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()
    Thread.sleep(20) //allow indexing to complete
    dbcomponent.driver.close()
  }

  // tests...

}
```

Is there a better way to do this besides using Thread.sleep?

Comment: Common practice is use `Future` for long time operations. You can [await](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/concurrent/Await$.html) future by `Await.result` or `aFuture.onComplete` (see docs). E.g., you can create `def index(...): Future[IndexCompleteResult]`, and than use it in `def init(...): Future[InitResult]`, and than use it in test: `Await.result(....init(...), Duration(1, TimeUnit.Minute))`.
Another way is use event-driven programming

Comment: yeah, I can't do that as I don't own the library. I mix in a trait which has this index creation thing going on. When I instantiate my repo class it runs that bit to create the index. Bad library design.

Comment: May be you can check status of index creation? In this case you can use `Promise` and/or (`while` + `Thread.sleep`). In you have some code with bad design, just wrap it in code with a good design (if you can)

Comment: What is wrong with the `Thread.sleep` solution?